# In the job History not finding any records even the job is getting success

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Index maintenece job is running weekly any and it is succefully happening every week.  But tables in that perticular database still fragmented above 90%.
In the job history it is not showing any records of the job. But in the job activity moniter it is showing job is succefully happening. How can i find the problem. please can any one help me on this.

Comment: In the notifications section of the job, make sure that "Write to the windows Application event log" is checked, this will write messages when it fails.  Have you manually started it?  Is it enabled?  How is it scheduled to start, make sure it isn't run once and it was a date in the past.  All things I have run across

Comment: Also in the last step, go to the advanced section and make sure that "on success action" says quit job reporting success and "on failure action" is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that  some body is cleaning the history of msdb on regular basis. So that's why am not finding any records in the job history.And That's why it is showing the success reports in the job log.